# Missing 'Connect to Source' Option - only Page environment is appearing

Tags: spfx

I have utilized the source code to create a shared data WebPart, but I am encountering an issue where the 'Connect to Source' option is not visible. When configuring the sender WebPart, I can only see the 'Page' environment as the available source. Strangely, when running the WebPart in debug mode/ workbench, the 'events source' starts appearing. I have also developed other WebParts that rely on dynamic data (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data), and they all face the same problem when deployed to a live site page ( SP online). Could there have been any changes related to 'IDynamicDataCallables' causing this issue? Please advice.

Configuration

```
 gulp -v CLI version: 2.3.0 Local version: 4.0.2

 node -v v14.15.0
```

package.json

```
{
   "name":"dynamicdata-test",
   "version":"0.0.1",
   "private":true,
   "main":"lib/index.js",
   "scripts":{
      "build":"gulp bundle",
      "clean":"gulp clean",
      "test":"gulp test"
   },
   "dependencies":{
      "@pnp/spfx-controls-react":"^1.19.0",
      "@types/es6-promise":"0.0.33",
      "react":"16.9.0",
      "react-dom":"16.9.0",
      "office-ui-fabric-react":"7.156.0",
      "@microsoft/sp-core-library":"1.12.1",
      "@microsoft/sp-property-pane":"1.12.1",
      "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base":"1.12.1",
      "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset":"1.12.1",
      "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core":"1.12.1"
   },
   "devDependencies":{
      "@types/react":"16.9.36",
      "@types/react-dom":"16.9.8",
      "@microsoft/sp-build-web":"1.12.1",
      "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules":"1.12.1",
      "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces":"1.12.1",
      "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench":"1.12.1",
      "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.7":"0.2.3",
      "gulp":"~4.0.2",
      "ajv":"~5.2.2",
      "@types/webpack-env":"1.13.1"
   }
}
```